# How to properly delegate an object?

Tags: javascript, oop

I want to create my own DOM object type:

```
var Obj = function(id) {
  this.id = id;
  this.constructor.prototype = document.getElementById(id);
};

var x = new Obj("a_div"); //Success
alert(x.type); //Successfully alert "div"
x.innerHTML = "TEST"; //This does not update the actual div html on the page!!!
```

I want any function call to this object would be forwarded to the actual DOM object. How can I achieve this?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work the way you describe (`div` is not alerted): http://jsfiddle.net/y3Je3/1/

Comment: Are you trying to extend the div object?  I don't think you can.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I wanna delegate it..

Comment: @texasbruce: I'm not quite sure you can.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker It worked when I tested on chrome. Will retest

Comment: This should work okay, except on IE probably :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do something like this :

```
var Obj = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
};
```

that you're basically aliasing the getElementById to Obj for shorthand notation. Granted, your x.type doesn't work like expected, but i'm sure that can be fixed.

You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Nemesis02/HwxDL/

Update:

```
var Obj = function(id) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  el.type = function() {
        // do something here
  }
  return el;
};
```

Comment: because i want to wrap more functions and data to the object

Answer (score 0):

I have partial success with code

```
var Obj = function(id) {
  this.id = id;
  this.__proto__ =  document.getElementById(id);
};
```

but when try to read/write innerHTML in Firefox it shows error:
`TypeError: 'innerHTML' getter called on an object that does not implement interface Element.`
 So I guess there is some limitations by browsers DOM implementation.